# Code from other sites shows up in my page.- Is this a security Issue

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I am working on a new web page for a site behind a firewall.  I am using firebug to help debug the script.  I have a small error on one of my dropdown boxes, but if I have been on another page in recent history, instead of the error showing up in my .js file, I show an error in another domain's script.  It doesn't look like I can load images, so I will try my best to discribe what this looks like.
I go to a page like reddit and look around.  The console box for firebug onfirefox is open at the bottom of the page and is empty.  I go to my test web site and navigate to my new page, all this time the console is empty.  When I change the selection in my dropdown box, I will get a strange error message.  There will be the normal Error:Syntax error, unrecognized expression in red.  But under it in green will be code that I haven't seen before and in the lower right is a url from another domain.  For example I often get: www.redditstatic.com/reddit-init.enIY9PAdp1eOs.js I can see all 147 lines of the reddit code and I am 4 pages into my own web site.  I tried setting my headders  but that didn't seem to help either.

Is this a security Issue since the reddit (or other) code is trying to run on my page?
Thanks so much for the help.
Brita

Comment: Are you including a script from that domain? If so, it is not totally uncommon for a script to actually write a new `script` element into your DOM. Google analytics does this for instance.

Comment: I am not adding script from that domain or any other domain for that matter.  All of my script is internal.  As a matter of fact our test server is behind a firewall, so everything is private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds very much like a bug in Firebug's error-logging code (it does some pretty terrifying things to try to figure out where things are coming from). Which means it is completely harmless and can be ignored, but if you feel like giving exact STR on how to get that error (possibly replacing the HTML of your internal site by a single button `<button onclick="syntax error">a`), including which Console filters are set, I'll be happy to take a look at fixing it.

Comment: I think you might be right about firebug.  I stepped through the script.  It starts with my code: 
$("select.chooseOption").change(function(){
 $("."+this.id).hide();
 $("."+$(this).val()).show();
});

Comment: I think you might be right about firebug.  I stepped through the script.  It starts with my code: 
$("select.chooseOption").change(function(){
 $("."+this.id).hide();
 $("."+$(this).val()).show();
});

Then it goes to jquery-1.9.1.js and I continue to step through the code.  
When I get to this line:
 jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
I get the unrecognized expression from the other site.
Have you heard of anything like this before?
Thanks,
Brita

Comment: I certainly don't have any problem imagining it. The actual problem is something to due with lazy parsing of event handlers, not doing JS execution when the error happens, and Firebug thus stealing a stack from an earlier error (from another tab). But I can't reproduce it from the information you've given, so it's unfixable without more information (steps to reproduce and such).

Comment: Thanks ever so much Simon.  This makes me feel so much better.  Since it is just a firebug issue and there is nothing sinister going on, I am content to ignore the message.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some reasons why you may see generated JavaScript code in your site:

1. Advertisers like Google AdSense would inject ads related code into
   your webpage to display ads.
2. Like, share, recommend, post etc.
   buttons also generate code for sharing content with social media.

Since the link you got was from [reddit.com](http://reddit.com), I suspect it's from a share button somewhere in the site. Here are some common buttons used for sharing: [reddit buttons.](http://www.reddit.com/buttons/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Zorayr,Thanks for the reply.  How can they inject ads related to my code in my webpage if I don't use any reddit code ANY place in the web site.  What do you think of Simon's response above that it may just be a firebug error?

Comment: It's not really, "they injecting it", as much as a developer on your side has included a script tag somewhere to import a JS file so Google or another advertiser could put ads on your site and monetize your equity, and in return pay your per-click or per impression. It's a standard approach.